# MVC post complex HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to post complex model property to `HttpPostedFileBase`.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(AlbumImagesLoc entity, int albumId, HttpPostedFileBase ImageUrl)
    { }
```

**View**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AlbumImage.ImageUrl, new { type = "file" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumImage.ImageUrl)
```

The problem now is the `HttpPostedFileBase` is always `null`, because its name must be `AlbumImage.ImageUrl`.

How can I avoid the `null` in the MVC code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlbumImagesLoc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AlbumImage ImageUrl { get; set; }  
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return View(new AlbumImagesLoc());
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(AlbumImagesLoc entity, int albumId)
{
   var albumImagesLoc = new AlbumImagesLoc();
   albumImagesLoc.Name = clientViewModel.Name;
   albumImagesLoc.AlbumImage.Add(AlbumImagesLoc.ImageUrl);
   db.AlbumImagesLoc.Add(albumImagesLoc);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AlbumImage.ImageUrl, new { type = "file" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumImage.ImageUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the View and see for "encetype"

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, 
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```